# Append the end of a url to my json jQuery code

Tags: jquery, json

I wish to append the end of a url to my jQuery code, I need to add the 'USD' part to my code. How can I add the end of the url (USD) to my original code below?

Original web link: http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD.

```
function collection() {
    $.getJSON('http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=', function(data) {
        //url += "USD";
        $("#show").text(data.rates.GBP);
    });
}
```

Comment: try: 
`code` var url = window.location.href;
 window.location.href = url+"USD";

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var url = window.location.href; 
window.location.href = url+"?base=USD";
```

Comment: `+=` would negate the need for the extra variable.

Comment: @taplar yes, but i tryed made this simplest.

Comment: An extra variable is more simple than a built in operator?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest appending the USD value to URL query string before invoking AJAX call to server side. You could rewrite `collection` function to accept an argument to complete the URL string.

My suggestion:

```
function collection(param) {
    $.getJSON('http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=' + param, function(data) {
        //url += "USD";
        $("#show").text(data.rates.GBP);
    });
}
```